# Can anyone explain this bitwise function to compute log(n)

Tags: c, logic, bitwise-operators

```
int howManyBits(int x) {
    int concatenate;
    int bias;
    int sign = x >> 31;  //get the sign
    x = (sign & (~x)) | (~sign & x); 
    concatenate = (!!(x >> 16)) << 4;
    concatenate |= (!!(x >> (concatenate + 8))) << 3;
    concatenate |= (!!(x >> (concatenate + 4))) << 2;
    concatenate |= (!!(x >> (concatenate + 2))) << 1;
    concatenate |= x >> (concatenate + 1);
    bias = !(x ^ 0);
    return concatenate + 2 + (~bias + 1);

}
```

This code is presented as a way to calculate the minimum number of bits required to represent an integer `n` in 2's complement, with the assumption that the `int` data type is represented with 32 bits. Right shifting is assumed to be arithmetic.

I understand that the basic method is to take the log base 2 of `n`, round it up, and then add 1 bit to account for the sign bit.

I also understand that left-shifting is equivalent to multiplying by 2 and that right-shifting is equivalent to dividing by 2.

That being said, without comments I can't decipher what this code is doing beyond the portion where it obtains the value of the sign bit. I worked through it on pencil and paper with a sample `int` of the value 5 - the code works, but I don't understand why.

Could someone provide some intuitive breakdown of what the code is doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code could use some comments.

This leaves x as it is if it is positive or takes the one's complement if negative.  This allows the calculation to search for the most significant one regardless of positive or negative

```
x = (sign & (~x)) | (~sign & x);
```

I think the following would have been more clear:

```
x = sign ? ~x : x;
```

Next is a search for the highest 1 bit done with a binary search. First the top half of the word is searched.

```
concatenate = (!!(x >> 16)) << 4;
```

If the top half has a 1, then the result is 16. The 16 is used later both as part of the answer, but also to determine where to search next.  Since it is used in the shifts that follow it will cause the following tests to either be done with the top half of the board or the bottom half.

The following concatenate operations are searching in a progressively smaller piece of the original number looking is the most significant one in the upper 8 bits or the lower 8 bits of the 16 bits that was chosen, then the upper 4 bits or the lower 4 bits of the 8 bits that was chosen, and so forth.

```
concatenate |= (!!(x >> (concatenate + 8))) << 3; // Check which 8 bits
concatenate |= (!!(x >> (concatenate + 4))) << 2; // Check which 4 bits
concatenate |= (!!(x >> (concatenate + 2))) << 1; // Check which 2 bits
concatenate |= x >> (concatenate + 1);            // Check which 1 bit
```

The bias is just checking is the number 0 or not.  It is 1 only if x is 0.  I don't understand the need for the XOR operator.

Finally the pieces are added together.